# Switching a fluorescent ECG with normal relays

Tags: ac, relay, ballast

I want to switch a ballast with a relay. The target lamp is rated at 120 W, but the (electronic) ballast states a 55 A inrush current. Does this mean that as soon as the relay is closed, 55 A will be passing through the relay contact?

What kind of relay would I need for such a task and what ratings should it have? Is a normal 5 VDC relay rated at 250 VAC/10 A enough for this?

Here is the relay I want to use: [Omron G5LE](https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-g5le.pdf)

Comment: Probably yes. You need to check the datasheet for the relay in question to tell for sure. Can you provide a link to the datasheet for it?

Comment: What is a "fluorescent ECG"?

Comment: @elliot Electronic control gear ie as opposed to magnetic

Comment: @winny Thanks for your input. I added the datasheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an electronic ballast, the TV-x ratings are most applicable.

The G5LE falls just a hair short with a TV-3 rating (51A inrush maximum, 3A steady-state). G5LE-E has a TV-8 rating (117A inrush 8A steady-state) at 40°C.

Those ratings apply for both UL and CSA, note they apply to the N.O. contact **only** at up to 40°C **only** and you only get 25,000 operations life.

[image]

More on ratings [here](https://components.omron.com/us-en/products/basic-knowledge/relays/applications)